# My Tic Tac Toe game thinks there's a winner whenever there's any 3 symbols in a row. How can I fix this?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm making a simple tic tac toe game but there's a pretty big issue. Basically, whenever there are any 3 symbols in a row (not necessarily 3 O's or 3 X's, just any three, the game thinks someone has won). I know that this is an issue with my checkWin method, but I'm not exactly sure what.

Something to note is that I named my buttons 1-10 instead of 0-9 which was a bad idea in hindsight as arrays start from 0. I think this might be causing my issue.

Here's what I've got so far with a screenshot of the app.

Many thanks,

Luke

```
package com.example.tictactoe;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private TextView PlayerOneScore, PlayerTwoScore, winStatus;
private Button [] mButtons = new Button[10];
private Button reset;

private int PlayerOneScoreCount, PlayerTwoScoreCount, roundCount;
boolean PlayerTurn;

int [] gameState = {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2};

int [][] winStates = {
        {1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9},
        {1,4,7},{2,5,8},{3,6,9},
        {1,5,9},{3,5,7}};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    PlayerOneScore = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.P1Score);
    PlayerTwoScore = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.P2Score);
    winStatus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.winStatus);

    reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset);

    for (int i=1; i < mButtons.length; i++){
        String buttonID = "btn" + i;
        int resourceID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id", getPackageName());
        mButtons[i] = (Button) findViewById(resourceID);
        mButtons[i].setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    roundCount = 0;
    PlayerOneScoreCount = 0;
    PlayerTwoScoreCount = 0;
    PlayerTurn = true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (!((Button)v).getText().toString().equals("")){
        return;
    }
    String buttonID = v.getResources().getResourceEntryName(v.getId());
    int gameStatePointer = Integer.parseInt(buttonID.substring
            (buttonID.length()-1, buttonID.length()));

    if (PlayerTurn){
        ((Button)v).setText("X");
        ((Button)v).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#545454"));
        gameState[gameStatePointer] = 0;
    }else {
        ((Button)v).setText("O");
        ((Button)v).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F2EBD3"));
        gameState[gameStatePointer] = 0;
    }
    roundCount++;

    if(checkWin()){
        if(PlayerTurn){
            PlayerOneScoreCount++;
            updatePlayerScore();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Player One Won!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            playAgain();
        }else {
            PlayerTwoScoreCount++;
            updatePlayerScore();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Player Two Won!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            playAgain();
        }

    }else if(roundCount == 9){
        playAgain();
        Toast.makeText(this, "It's a Draw!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else {
        PlayerTurn = !PlayerTurn;
    }

    if (PlayerOneScoreCount > PlayerTwoScoreCount){
        winStatus.setText("Player One is Winning!");
    }else if (PlayerTwoScoreCount > PlayerOneScoreCount){
        winStatus.setText("Player Two is Winning!");
    }else {
        winStatus.setText("");
    }

    reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playAgain();
            PlayerOneScoreCount = 0;
            PlayerTwoScoreCount = 0;
            winStatus.setText("");
            updatePlayerScore();
        }
    });
}

public boolean checkWin(){
    boolean Winner = false;

    for (int [] winningState : winStates){
        if (gameState[winningState[0]] == gameState[winningState[1]] &&
                gameState[winningState[1]] == gameState[winningState[2]] &&
                    gameState[winningState[0]]!=2){
            Winner = true;
        }
    }
    return Winner;
}

public void updatePlayerScore(){
    PlayerOneScore.setText(Integer.toString(PlayerOneScoreCount));
    PlayerTwoScore.setText(Integer.toString(PlayerTwoScoreCount));
}

public void playAgain(){
    roundCount = 0;
    PlayerTurn = true;

    for (int i = 1; i < mButtons.length; i++){
        gameState[i] = 2;
        mButtons[i].setText("");
    }
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `checkWin()` you iterate through the various winning states to see if any of the players has won by comparing all `Button`s which "belong" to a given winning state.

Since you always set the game state value to zero if a `Button` has been clicked, no matter whose turn it is, you will have a "winner" as soon as all `Button`s belonging to one winning state have been clicked.

**TL;DR**  You can fix the issue by setting different values in `onClick()` depending on whose turn it is:

```
    if (PlayerTurn){
        ((Button)v).setText("X");
        ((Button)v).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#545454"));
        gameState[gameStatePointer] = 1;
    }else {
        ((Button)v).setText("O");
        ((Button)v).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F2EBD3"));
        gameState[gameStatePointer] = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you both! I knew it was something really small like this! It works perfectly now, thank you so much for the help! <3

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure, but I think it might be the values you set in your gamestate. As far as I can see, you are always setting it to 0 in your onClick method

```java
if (PlayerTurn){
        ((Button)v).setText("X");
        ((Button)v).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#545454"));
        gameState[gameStatePointer] = 0;
    }else {
        ((Button)v).setText("O");
        ((Button)v).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F2EBD3"));
        gameState[gameStatePointer] = 0;
    }
```

Then when you are checking, whether the values in the gamestate are equal every field, which was clicked has a 0 in it, so the they are equal. You probably wanted to set on of them to another integer